# How to "rewrite" existing vim key bindings?

Tags: vim, vim-tabular

I want to assign <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to go the next tab (`:tabnext`). I placed it at `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap <c-l> :tabnext<CR>
```

It worked fine, but I faced with a case when it doesn't work when I split screen on several windows. It seems that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> conflicts with "redraw screen" action assigned by default. For example, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on the center window I get nothing (see the screenshot):

[image]

However when I press the same on either left or right windows it works fine..
I think I need to "rewrite" the default action, doesn't it?

*I use vim from terminal.*

Comment: I believe it's rather the case that the plugin that manages your center window does its own `nmap <c-l>`, and overwrites your binding (as plugins are executed after `.vimrc`). Check if the plugin has configuration variables that will prevent the binding; if not, you might either need to edit the plugin to remove the binding, or put your binding in a file that is executed later.

Comment: I don't use any custom plugins, just Vim 7.4 installed by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know Vim good and use it less than 1 week, please could you explain in more details what you mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The window in the middle, if I am not mistaken, is netrw (Vim's standard plugin for file management). It is not a custom plugin, but it is a plugin nevertheless.

If you take a look at `:help netrw-ctrl-l`, you will see that it is not just a redraw - it also refreshes the directory. So it is mapped from the plugin, overriding the default ctrl-l mapping for netrw windows only.

If you execute `:verbose nmap <c-l>` in that window, you will see exactly where it is defined: in `autoload/netrw.vim` file in your Vim installation. Looking there, we find this snippet:

```
if !hasmapto('<Plug>NetrwRefresh')
 nmap <buffer> <unique> <c-l> <Plug>NetrwRefresh
 imap <buffer> <unique> <c-l> <Plug>NetrwRefresh
endif
```

Which says, if `<Plug>NetrwRefresh` is not bound to anything, then bind `<c-l>`. This presents an easy solution: since `netrw.vim` is, like everything else, loaded after `.vimrc`, if you define those mappings to some other key, they won't be assigned to `<c-l>`, and your mapping will not be overridden. So just do this in your `.vimrc`:

```
 nmap <unique> <c-r> <Plug>NetrwRefresh
```

However, a better way would be to not step on Vim's toes.

Comment: Now I have the following in `.vimrc`: `nmap <unique> <c-p> <Plug>NetrwRefresh \n
nmap <c-l> :tabnext<CR> \n
nmap <c-h> :tabprevious<CR>`. But it still doesn't work. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Netrw v155a (see http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW) addresses this issue by mapping a ctrl-L differently; it now invokes a (not-remapped) ctrl-L as part of its refresh.  As a consequence, even when in a netrw window, the ctrl-L will work to refresh all windows.