# What does <unique> mean in vim?

Tags: vim

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351179/how-to-rewrite-existing-vim-key-bindings) I tried to "rewrite" default mapping of Netrw's `NetrwRefresh` command. The default mapping was `<c-l>` and I wanted to free it for different purpose. Suggested solution was the following:

```
nmap <unique> <c-r> <Plug>NetrwRefresh
" from now on I can use <c-l> for whatever I want
```

Everything is fine, but when I try to change `<c-r>` to `<leader>xx` every time I get this error:

[image]

Whatever I place after `<leader>` the error always occur. I tried to remove `<unique>` and I get the result. So the question is: what the `<unique>` is intended for?

Comment: Check `:help unique`:  _"If the first argument to one of these commands is "<unique>" and it is used to define a new mapping or abbreviation, the command will fail if the mapping or abbreviation already exists"_

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, yes! Post it as the answer. But if so, how can I check if `<leader>xx` is already in use elsewhere?

Comment: It seems strange that whatever you place after `<leader>` fails with `<unique>` It seems you should able to find _some_ combination which is not already in use.  Check the output from simply running `:map` to see what is using all your leader mappings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, Vim's `:help` command should point you in the right direction.  From `:help unique`, is documented:

> If the first argument to one of these commands is "" and it is used to define a new mapping or abbreviation, the command will fail if the mapping or abbreviation already exists

So Vim is telling you that a mapping already exists for `<leader>xx` and refuses to overwrite it.  To determine what is already using `<leader>xx` in your setup, you may view all mappings:

```
:map
```

It seems unusual and somewhat unlikely that *anything* you try following `<leader>` is already in use, so examining the output from `:map` should reveal some available combinations.